# Numpy : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy

I am really confused on why this error is showing up. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 0])
y = np.array([10, 10])
a = np.array([1, 6])
b = np.array([3, 7])
points = [x, y, a, b]
max_pair = [x, y]
other_pairs = [p for p in points if p not in max_pair]
>>>ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
(a not in max_paix)
>>>ValueError: The truth ...
```

What confuses me is that the following works fine:

```
points = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7]]
max_pair = [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
other_pairs = [p for p in points if p not in max_pair]
>>>[[3, 4], [5, 7]]
([5, 6] not in max_pair)
>>>False
```

Why is this happening when using numpy arrays? Is `not in/in` ambiguous for existance?
What is the correct syntax using `any()\all()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numpy arrays define a custom equality operator, i.e. they are objects that implement the `__eq__` magic function. Accordingly, the `==` operator and all other functions/operators that rely on such an equality call this custom equality function.

Numpy's equality is based on element-wise comparison of arrays. Thus, in return you get another numpy array with boolean values. For instance:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([1,4,5])
x == y
```

returns

```
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

However, the `in` operator in combination with *lists* requires equality comparisons that only return a **single** boolean value. This is the reason why the error asks for `all` or `any`. For instance:

```
any(x==y)
```

returns `True` because at least one value of the resulting array is `True`.
In contrast

```
all(x==y)
```

returns `False` because **not** all values of the resulting array are `True`.

So in your case, a way around the problem would be the following:

```
other_pairs = [p for p in points if all(any(p!=q) for q in max_pair)]
```

and `print other_pairs` prints the expected result

```
[array([1, 6]), array([3, 7])]
```

Why so? Well, we look for an item *p* from *points* where **any** of its entries are unequal to the entries of **all** items *q* from *max_pair*.

Comment: *the in operator requires equality comparisons* that was very helpful! The result I want to get (`not in`) is obtained with `[p for p in points if all(any(p!=q) for q in max_pair)]`.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry I correct that :-), missed the `not in`.

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind is that they're two different objects completely. `np.array` has it's own operators that work on it.

They are named the same as the global operators `any` and `all` but don't work exactly the same, and that distinction is reflected in the fact they are methods of `np.array`.

```
>>> x = np.array([0,9])
>>> x.any(axis=0)
True
>>> y = np.array([10, 10])
>>> y.all()
True
>>> y.all(axis=0)
True
```

meanwhile:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([[]])
True
>>> bool([[]][0])
False
```

Notice how first result is false (in python2) an empty list is deemed `False`. However a list with another list in it, even if that one is empty, is not `False` but `True`. Evaluating the inside list returns `False` again because it's empty. Since `any` and `all` are defined over the conversion to `bool` the results you see are different.

```
>>> help(all)
all(...)
    all(iterable) -> bool
    Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.

>>> help(any)
any(...)
    any(iterable) -> bool
    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
```

See a better explanations for logical numpy operators [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html)