# Python - Truth Value of array is ambiguous (If statement for facial recognition)

Tags: python

I have a face recognition file that searches a folder for 'Known' faces then searches another folder to try and see those face.

To search through the folder of known faces I have:

```
my_dir = './img/known/'
encoding_for_file = []
for i in os.listdir(my_dir):
    image = my_dir + i
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image)
    image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)
    encoding_for_file.append(image_encoding[0])
```

The code then searches a folder for a face and if it finds one, shows the image.

```
for i in range (1, 8+1):

    #Construct the picture name and print it
    file_name = f"./img/unknown/{str(i).zfill(5)}.jpg"
    print(file_name)

    #Load the file
    newPic = face_recognition.load_image_file(file_name)

    #Search every detected face
    for face_encoding in face_recognition.face_encodings(newPic):


        results = face_recognition.compare_faces([image_encoding], face_encoding)

        #If match, show it
        if results[0] == True:
            img = Image.open(file_name)
            img.show()
```

However I get a "**Truth Value of Array is ambiguous** error on the following line:

```
if results[0] == True:
```

It suggests using a.any() or a.all() - which I have not used.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the output when you execute `print(results[0])`?

Comment: [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
]

Comment: @mp.jpeg This stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900165/7548672 I think gives a good explanation to your error and why the suggestion is to use any() or all().